# How to retrieve data from an Object in an Array in Vue.js

Tags: api, vue.js, vue-resource

I have an `Array` with an `Object` with multiple `Objects` in them with the use of `Vue.js`.

**See it like this:**

```
tree: [{
  stick: {
    leaf:{
      name: "Vincent"
    },
    sheet:{
      name: "Charles"
    },
    paper:{
      name: "Harry"
    }
  }
]}
```

**Now my question is:** How do I reach the name of a leaf?

Answer (score 0):

This could not work. You set the `leaf` property multiple times which is not supported. I assume you would do something like:

```
var myvar = {stick: [
  {leaf: {name: "Vincent"}}, 
  {leaf: {name: "Charles"}},
  ...
]};

console.log(myvar.stick[0].leaf.name);
```

Comment: I have changed the `array` so that `leaf` is unique, but the focuspoint in my question was how I could reach `data` nested in an `object`, nested in an `object`, nested in an `array`.

Comment: For my example: `myvar.stick[0].leaf.name`

Comment: Yes, but in your example `stick` is an `array` and not an `object`

Comment: exactly! This is why i use the `stick[0]` notation which references the `0th` elem in the array

Comment: Yes, okay... But my `data` is recursive, so I don't always want the first object in the array. Maybe you can look to this link/. Here is my `HTML-code`.

Comment: http://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-retrieve-data-from-an-object-in-an-object-in-an-array/1267/6

Answer (score 0):

You'd want `tree[0].stick.leaf.name` with the data you have.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I call the name with my `HTML-code`? Putting this between curly brackets doesn't help

Comment: Are you working in a loop? I find this situation a little weird and think you need to give more details.

Comment: Yes, the API is recursive thus I need to loop through the array. If you check out this link, you'll see snippets of my code: http://forum.vuejs.org/t/2-errors/1273